# Returning whole string with preg_split

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm trying to split a string by one or more spaces, but the below isn't working..instead it is returning the whole string as a singular array.

```
$str = 'I am a test';

$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $str, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($parts);
```

Here is what it returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => I am a test
)
```

Comment: I mean a single value in the array only. I have edited my post to show what is returned.

Comment: `flags` is the *4th* parameter to [`preg_split`](http://us.php.net/preg-split), not the *3rd*.

Comment: @DCoder Thanks. That fixed it. If you posted your response as an answer I could accept your answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`flags` is the *4th* parameter to [`preg_split`](http://us.php.net/preg-split), not the *3rd*.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag: `$parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $str);`

Comment: Isn't the point of that flag so you won't get any empty array values though? Why do you need to remove it?